# Is the diract delta function a unique identity under convolution?

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

I just thought about how amazing of a coincidence it is that this limit object as an offshoot of the Weierstrass approximation theorem and proofs of Fourier series ended up also being the identity under convolution operations.

But then I thought "wait, maybe there's infinitely many different identities..."

Is the Dirac delta distribution the only distribution such that for another distribution $f,$ $f * \delta = f$?

Comment: Suppose there were two identity distributions, $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. Then $\delta_1 = \delta_1 * \delta_2 = \delta_2$.

Comment: Are identities on any space always unique if they exist? Is there an example where such an argument fails?

Comment: Doesn't Rob's argument always work, Stack?

Comment: In general, the order matters. If there is a semigroup $G$ with an operation $*$, then there can be a "right identity" $e_r$ such that $ge_r = g$ for each $g$, while $e_rg \neq g$ in general. Likewise, there can be a left identity. But if there are both right identities and left identities, then they actually must be the same (and be a 'two-sided' identity), since again $e_l = e_l * e_r = e_r$

Comment: If there are only identities of one side, then there is not necessarily a unique one

Comment: Well I don't think a general algebraic argument fits here, because perhaps $f$ represents a function rather than a distribution. But I have read that: If $T_n\to T$, $S_n\to S$ as distributions and $\operatorname{supp}S_n\subset K$ for some compact $K$, then $T_n\star S_n\to T\star S$. If I take an approximation of unity $\{\chi_n\}$, then for an identity distribution $T$ of convolution, we have $\chi_n = T\circ\chi_n\to T\circ\delta=T$ (that is to say $T_n = T$ and $S_n=\chi_n$), so $T=\delta$.